# Keras: unsupervised pre-training kills performance

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, autoencoder

I'm trying to train a deep classifier in Keras both with and without pretraining of the hidden layers via stacked autoencoders. My problem is that the pretraining seems to drastically degrade performance (i.e. if `pretrain` is set to `False` in the code below the training error of the final classification layer converges much faster). This seems completely outrageous to me given that pretraining should only initialize the weights of the hidden layers and I don't see how that could completely kill the models performance even if that initialization does not work very well. I can not include the specific dataset I used but the effect should occur for any appropriate dataset (e.g. minist). What is going on here and how can I fix it?

EDIT: code is now **reproducible** with the MNIST data, final line prints change in loss function, which is significantly lower with pre-training.
I have also slightly modified the code and added sample learning curves below:

[image]

```
from functools import partial

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.regularizers import l2
from keras.utils import to_categorical

(inputs_train, targets_train), _ = mnist.load_data()

inputs_train = inputs_train[:1000].reshape(1000, 784)
targets_train = to_categorical(targets_train[:1000])

hidden_nodes = [256] * 4
learning_rate = 0.01
regularization = 1e-6
epochs = 30

def train_model(pretrain):
    model = Sequential()

    layer = partial(Dense,
                    activation='sigmoid',
                    kernel_initializer='random_normal',
                    kernel_regularizer=l2(regularization))

    for i, hn in enumerate(hidden_nodes):
        kwargs = dict(units=hn, name='hidden_{}'.format(i + 1))

        if i == 0:
            kwargs['input_dim'] = inputs_train.shape[1]

        model.add(layer(**kwargs))

    if pretrain:
        # train autoencoders
        inputs_train_ = inputs_train.copy()

        for i, hn in enumerate(hidden_nodes):
            autoencoder = Sequential()

            autoencoder.add(layer(units=hn,
                                  input_dim=inputs_train_.shape[1],
                                  name='hidden'))

            autoencoder.add(layer(units=inputs_train_.shape[1],
                                  name='decode'))

            autoencoder.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=learning_rate, momentum=0.9),
                                loss='binary_crossentropy')

            autoencoder.fit(
                inputs_train_,
                inputs_train_,
                batch_size=32,
                epochs=epochs,
                verbose=0)

            autoencoder.pop()

            model.layers[i].set_weights(autoencoder.layers[0].get_weights())

            inputs_train_ = autoencoder.predict(inputs_train_)

    num_classes = targets_train.shape[1]

    model.add(Dense(units=num_classes,
                    activation='softmax',
                    name='classify'))

    model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=learning_rate, momentum=0.9),
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy')

    h = model.fit(
        inputs_train,
        targets_train,
        batch_size=32,
        epochs=epochs,
        verbose=0)

    return h.history['loss']

plt.plot(train_model(pretrain=False), label="Without Pre-Training")
plt.plot(train_model(pretrain=True), label="With Pre-Training")

plt.xlabel("Epoch")
plt.ylabel("Cross-Entropy")

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: If you believe indeed that "*the effect should occur for any appropriate dataset (e.g. mnist)*", then please post a [Minimal, Compete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using the MNIST data...

Comment: I tried automatically downloading the dataset with some of the methods available in scikit-learn, tensorflow etc. All of those fail for some reason of another or are not available in newer versions. If I just load some textfile in the code above that's not going to help anyone. I will try to find some way around this.

Comment: Alright, should work now

Comment: Good job - upvoted & removed close vote... Only thing is, can you share the actual *results* you get with MNIST?